# Socket.io passing paramaters

Tags: json, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently using `Socket.io` with `Node.js`.

I want to use/passing `x` parameters on the `on` method, but it doesn't works.

Here is the basic example, on client side, I'm using th the following method:

```
socket.tell('createRoom', 'My Room Name');
```

On server side I registered event with following line:

```
socket.on('createRoom', function(name) {
    // Handling...
    console.log('Create the new room ' + name);
});
```

It work's fine. The second parameter will be passed on the `on`-Method. But when I try to add another parameter, there will be not passed on the `anonymous` function, here is the sample:

```
socket.tell('createRoom', 'My Room Name', { roomProperty1: 'Hello', roomProperty2: 123 });

socket.on('createRoom', function(name, properties) {
    // Handling...
    console.log('Create the new room ' + name + ' with following properties: ' + JSON.stringify(properties));
});
```

Everytime the `properties` are `undefined`, but I cannot understand the reason.

Can anyone tell me, what's wrong? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: im not updated with the `tell` method but the second parameter should suppose to be data. you can pas in you object in the second parameter along with the name. `socket.tell('action', {name:...,age:...});`

Answer (score 0):

When I try your example I get

> TypeError: socket.tell is not a function

But when I run it with

```
socket.emit('createRoom', 'My Room Name', { roomProperty1: 'Hello', roomProperty2: 123 });
```

I get the expected output:

> Create the new room My Room Name with following properties: {"roomProperty1":"Hello","roomProperty2":123}